# 'const_missing': uninitialized constant Time::DATE_FORMATS (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, hudson

I'm having a problem when i try to run some ruby unit tests.

I'm getting the following stack in hudson:

```
/home/cpcaserver5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/ext/module.rb:36:in `const_missing': uninitialized constant Time::DATE_FORMATS (NameError)
    from /home/cpcaserver5/.hudson/jobs/SVN/workspace/Hermodr/trunk/server/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/cpcaserver5/.hudson/jobs/SVN/workspace/Hermodr/trunk/server/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `require'
    from /home/cpcaserver5/.hudson/jobs/SVN/workspace/Hermodr/trunk/server/test/test_helper.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/cpcaserver5/.hudson/jobs/SVN/workspace/Hermodr/trunk/server/test/unit/group_test.rb:1:in `require'
    from /home/cpcaserver5/.hudson/jobs/SVN/workspace/Hermodr/trunk/server/test/unit/group_test.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/cpcaserver5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `require'
    from /home/cpcaserver5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /home/cpcaserver5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `each'
    from /home/cpcaserver5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:9:in `block in <main>'
    from /home/cpcaserver5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `select'
    from /home/cpcaserver5/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb:4:in `<main>'
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [/home/cpcaserver5/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p...]
```

Comment: it's works on your own server ?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, the code was created by all team, them i'm having to support this problem.
But i've changed some paths in some files that was and this problem was solved, but to another files i can't do this. It's so weird ...

Comment: so ask to developer of this why have you this problem and how solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails supports multiple date formats, usually declared in an initializer in initializers/time.rb - for example:

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:short_date] = "%b %d, %Y"
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:full_date] = "%A, %B %d, %Y"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:short_slashed] = "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M %p"
Time::DATE_FORMATS[:short_date] = "%b %d, %Y"
```

This allows date.to_s(:short_date) to format the date output.   However, your error output indicates that this file has not been read, and as I don't see any output that indicates rails in your stack trace, I wonder if any rails files at all have been loaded.